# problem running third party deb packages in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm experiencing problems running some third party app (simplenote, tagspaces, superproductivity, zenkit) installed manually after downloading from their websites.
They worked perfectly for some days after installation. Now, when I try to start these apps nothing happens. They are installed in folder /opt. I have tried running executables from their folders using command line, cursor keeps blinking with zero output.
Where should i look(logs or something else)?

more information after looking into `syslog`

> Failed to find one package       for simplenote.desktop,
>   /usr/share/applications/simplenote.desktop,
>
> failed to rescan: Failed to       parse
>   /usr/share/applications/zenkit.desktop.dpkg-new file: cannot process file of type text/plain

Errors for other apps are similar.

Comment: Look in the logs `/var/log/syslog` or log files belonging to any of those programs

Comment: Also you can try to launch your applications from terminal and check their error output here.

Comment: It's possible that you've changed your environment at the (cog wheel icon) on the login screen. Trying using **Ubuntu** or **Ubuntu using X11/xorg**. Report back.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Thanks, for pointing in right direction. After looking into syslog I have updated the error.

Comment: @heynnema Tried both `ubuntu` and `ubuntu wayland` same results.

Comment: @ashwinids please give me a link to one of those apps let me try to install and replicate your error

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen [superproductivity](https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity/releases), [simplenote](https://simplenote.com/) and [zenkit](https://zenkit.com/en/apps/)

Comment: Lets do this run this `ls /usr/share/applications/zenkit.desktop` and post the result I think some of your desktop files have the wrong extension or so

Comment: Do you have **packagekit** and **packagekit-tools** installed? Do **dpkg -l package* | grep -i package** and report back to @heynnema.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it shows the desktop file is there. `output = /usr/share/applications/zenkit.desktop`

Comment: @heynnema I have synaptic manager. I've tried to downgrade the packages using synaptic. It didn't work because these are not from repos.

Comment: No, you don't want to downgrade anything. Use the **dpkg** command that I gave you to check if you have those two packagekit files installed.